# Excel/CSV - Convert key value to csv

Tags: excel, csv, export-to-csv

I have a column in Excel that has following records:

> {Property1=opt-in, Property2=opt-out, Property3=opt-out}
>   {Property1=opt-in, Property2=opt-out, Property3=opt-out}
>  
>   {Property1=opt-in, Property2=opt-in, Property3=opt-in}

Is there a way to convert it to csv or three separate columns

> Property1, Properyty2, Property3 
>   opt-out, opt-out, opt-in
>   opt-in, opt-in, opt-in
>   opt-out, opt-out, opt-in

Comment: Sure there's a way. btw, some level of original effort is pretty much **expected** from people asking for code.

Comment: No i am not asking for code. I can parse that, thank you. I was expecting a way of doing it in excel itself.

Comment: Text parsing using native excel functions only works for static numbers of items. If your samepl (JSON..?) data is truly representative of the input then yes, a formula could be constructed to split the rows into columns. fwiw, a VBA sub procedure would be a better fit and C#/VB.Net has some JSON libraries that would do the trick.

Comment: Not a real answer, but you could use the `Text to Columns` feature, use `=` and `,` as delimiters - That will give you the 3 columns you need together with the 3 headers each in a separate column you could easily remove... More of a hack, but it would do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

For demonstrations sake, put the column header labels into some unused cells to the right and use this standard formula directly below the first one.

```
=TRIM(LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(REPLACE($A1,1,SEARCH(C$1,$A1)+LEN(C$1),""),"}",","),",",REPT(" ",LEN($A1))), LEN($A1)))
```

Fill right and down.

[image: excel_split_json]

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;

import jxl.Cell;
import jxl.Sheet;
import jxl.Workbook;

public class ExcelReader {

    public void excel(String input) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {

            String S = "C:/Users/DELL/Desktop/workspace_luna/ecel dataload/"
                    + input;
            String S1 = "C:/Users/DELL/Desktop/workspace_luna/ecel dataload/"
                    + input.substring(0, input.indexOf('.')) + ".xls";
            File f = new File(S);

            @SuppressWarnings("resource")
            OutputStream os = (OutputStream) new FileOutputStream(f);

            String encoding = "UTF8";
            OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(os, encoding);

            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(osw);

            File f2 = new File(S1);

            Workbook w = Workbook.getWorkbook(f2);

            for (int sheet = 0; sheet < w.getNumberOfSheets(); sheet++) {
                Sheet s = w.getSheet(sheet);



                Cell[] row = null;


                for (int i = 0; i < s.getRows(); i++) {


                    row = s.getRow(i);

                    if (row.length > 0) {

                        bw.write(row[0].getContents());
                        for (int j = 1; j < row.length; j++) {
                            bw.write("||");

                            bw.write(row[j].getContents());
                        }
                    }

                    bw.newLine();
                }
            }
            bw.flush();
            bw.close();
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            System.err.println(e.toString());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println(e.toString());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e.toString());
        }
    }

}
```